# Can't delete folder and I am admin. "You need permission to perform this action. You require permission from..."

Tags: windows-7

I can't delete a certain folder in Windows 7. It's not a system folder. It was created by an app. I get an error message "You need permission to perform this action. You require permission from Tony....". I am an admin and logged in as myself Tony. I have full ownership of the folder with full control permission. I rebooted the machine. I killed the app which created the folder. I am out of ideas.

Why is Windows 7 not letting me delete the folder?

Comment: Have you got any background processes: TortoiseSVN, Anti-virus softwares, etc. that might be hanging on the folder (though I agree this is unlikely after a reboot). Alternatively have you tried deleting it while in safe mode?

Comment: No idea why, but if safe mode deletion doesn't work, you could boot your system from a live CD of some sort (like Linux) and go directly into the file system and delete the file.  This would undoubtedly work, but if some process is actually using the file, then it might break that process (when you reboot into Windows) with unknown consequences for the rest of your system, so make a backup of the file so you can put it back if things start to go south.

Comment: Just a thought: What are the attributes of the folder and everything under it?  If something is set to read only (or maybe system), then you would probably have to remove those attributes before you could delete it even if you own it and are an admin.  I haven't worked at that level in Windows for a long time, but that's how it used to work.

Comment: You are not an administrator. You are said that you have his rights. Wrongly. The receipt is very simple, look this answer below: http://superuser.com/a/1119561/134259

Comment: I am in the administrators group.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The only way was to delete files starting from the lowest level folder in that folder. I got that error message with every folder which had subfolders. I deleted all files/subfolders working my way up.

Comment: That's the only thing that worked for me as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293398/under-which-circumstances-does-the-system-process-pid-4-retain-an-open-file-ha. have a look here. worked for me

Comment: Try this: Properties -> Security -> Advanced.  Ensure the owner is assigned full control permissions.  Change Permissions, check "Replace all child object permissions...", Apply.  Now try to delete.  The analog solved same problem for me under Win8, if certain details are slightly different.

Comment: You may also want to restart, because we're on Windows and that's a thing. Drove me crazy for 15 minutes, but a restart fixed it after following Wilee's instructions.

Comment: I've built a small program [node-purgewindir](https://github.com/devotis/node-purgewindir) that does exactly that. Deletes a directory by deleting every subdirectory recursively starting with the deepest nested subdirectories first

Comment: why does this occur?

Comment: I can't do this because "Access is denied" when trying to open it.

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/1119561/134259

Comment: For me I just had to delete a single file, which was nested three levels deep, and then I could delete the rest. (Win 10)

Comment: Wow. This works even after 11 years.

Comment: If you can do this manually there must be a way to script it then?

Answer (score 163):

I am not sure why this happens but there is a workaround.

To take control of the folder that cannot be deleted, create a text file called `delete.bat` and add the following lines to it:

```
    SET DIRECTORY_NAME="C:\Locked Directory"
    TAKEOWN /f %DIRECTORY_NAME% /r /d y
    ICACLS %DIRECTORY_NAME% /grant administrators:F /t
    ICACLS %DIRECTORY_NAME% /reset /T
    PAUSE
```

You will need to change the directory path to match your requirements e.g. `C:\Locked Directory` to `C:\Delete Me`.

Right click on the file `delete.bat` select `Run As Administrator` and you should now have full control of the directory and all sub directories meaning you can do what you wish with them.

Comment: Tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: That is a bummer. I was faced with a similar issue on a Windows 7 (64 bit) machine and this worked like a charm.

Comment: It would have been nice if Microsoft fixed this bug in Sp1. This is a massive fail, and I curse each time I have to delete deep nested directories.

Comment: +1  I had two system owned folders on a secondary drive that were created by the OS prior to my Win 8 -> 8.1 upgrade.  Even through the Advanced Security dialog (MS's preferred approach), I could not take ownership to delete.  This worked like a charm.

Comment: Windows 8.1 - Files & Folders were created remotely through SMB, only this was able to take ownership. Afterwards I still could not remove the files (Error message told me to get permission from myself) but the Advanced Security Dialog was THEN able to fix the permissions using the inheritance clean-up checkbox. After this I could remove the files.

Comment: the second line just tells me "access is denied".

Comment: Now it says I need permission from myself to delete the directory.  I gave myself full control of the directory and logged out and back in. Same thing.

Comment: Both commands succeed, I now have ownership for 'Administror' to directory. I then had to do 'rmdir /s %DIRECTORY_NAME%' in order to delete directory, even though it was empty, otherwise I got 'Access is denied.'

Comment: This worked for me (up to a point), but only after I changed "administrators" to my own login name.  After that there were still a couple of files left that I could not delete because they were in use.  Now to find out what program is using them.

Comment: ERROR: The current logged on user does not have ownership privileges on "...." --- aka, doesn't work

Comment: Worked for me, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is the only thing that actually worked for me after trying too many things. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that both the /d y and administrator groups are language specific and you'll need to change those for the ones of the language of the OS

Comment: `D:\somepath\lib>TAKEOWN /f dlib /r /d y` Result:
`ERROR: Access is denied.`

Comment: whoa! I completely butchered the permissions for a folder on a network drive: The only assigned permissions was a `Deny` rule to delete the folder O.o I thought I was done for. I can't believe this worked (Ran `.bat` as a domain Administrator)

Comment: Same on Windows 10

Comment: After running the script, i attempted to delete my bizarre directory but only part of it was deleted. To delete the rest, I rebooted into safe mode, ran the script again and then I was able to delete them successfully!

Answer (score 36):

A folder can disallow a parent from overwriting its permissions, so it stops working at a certain depth.

Use [**Process Monitor**](http://download.sysinternals.com/Files/ProcessMonitor.zip) and filter for **ACCESS DENIED** events to figure out this depth

Every time an **ACCESS DENIED** event occurs change the permissions as [explained by @Sahil](https://superuser.com/questions/204909/cant-delete-folder-and-i-am-admin-you-need-permission-to-perform-this-action/204916#204916).

---

You can use [**Handle**](http://live.sysinternals.com/Files/Handle.zip) too see what processes are opening files within your folder.

```
handle C:\Path\To\Folder\You\Are\Trying\To\Delete
```

**Example:**

```
C:\Windows\system32>handle C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv

Handle v3.45
Copyright (C) 1997-2011 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

svchost.exe   pid: 1500  type: File  134: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\schema
svchost.exe   pid: 1500  type: File  1B4: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\schema
svchost.exe   pid: 1500  type: File  1BC: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config
svchost.exe   pid: 1500  type: File  1CC: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config
svchost.exe   pid: 1500  type: File  1D0: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config
inetinfo.exe  pid: 1572  type: File  3C:  C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\en-US\inetinfo.exe.mui
inetinfo.exe  pid: 1572  type: File  188: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\MBSchema.bin.00000000h
inetinfo.exe  pid: 1572  type: File  190: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\MBSchema.bin.00000000h
inetinfo.exe  pid: 1572  type: File  1BC: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\MetaBase.xml
inetinfo.exe  pid: 1572  type: File  1D4: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\MBSchema.xml
svchost.exe   pid: 1884  type: File  1AC: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\schema
svchost.exe   pid: 1884  type: File  1C0: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config
svchost.exe   pid: 1884  type: File  1C4: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config
```

Comment: This is a good tip. My problem was that I wanted to delete a folder, but I got an Access Denied error. The folder properties showed that I had no permissions to even change the ownership of the folder. I used Process Explorer and used the Find Handle search to find which process had a handle to the locked directory. Then I killed the process, and everything was working again.

Comment: Using `handle` command in cmd line is the only thing that worked for me!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `handle` utility helped a lot

Comment: The `handle` program was wonderful.

Comment: Worked great in Windows 10 too :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, with your information I've managed to detect which process has a handle associated with that folder without using external programs. Using Resource monitor from windows 10 on `CPU` tab > `Associated handles` panel and there I type the folder name in the search bar. And found the associated process Id.

Comment: Late to the party, but can confirm that this resolved my issue.

Answer (score 30):

Had this issue today with a Windows Update folder and would like to supplement the answer.

When permissions on a folder **are correct** (example below, with Admin being the administrator account I was logged in with):

[image]

**But permissions on subfolders are different** and **do not propagate** from the parent even though you tell them to, causing problems when trying to delete the parent folder:

[image]

Open a command prompt (personally, I did not need to elevate the prompt) and run

```
ICACLS <FolderName> /reset /T
```

[image]

To replace Access Control Lists with default ACLs, traversing all subfolders. After this try deleting the folder.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me: "Accès refusé." which mean "refused access". Thanks anyway, what a pain to get "root" access on windows pffff.:/ (I was in a command line started as administrator)

Comment: I'm getting `handle is invalid` error. Any idea what that means?

Comment: Windows 10 Enterprise. Worked for me!

Comment: Yes, i tried everything from above answers but the reason was the permissions were not propagated to the downstream folders and files and so had to lot of manual work to get everything deleted.

Comment: Another alternative is to actually, enable inheritance as discussed in the above answers.

Answer (score 17):

I had this issue and tried several of the answers here to no avail.  However, I was able to simply delete the entire folder I was having problems with from an *elevated* command prompt like so:

```
rmdir "C:\path\to\folder" /s
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This is exactly what I did too... can't believe I had to look through every answer to find someone else who did the same thing. IMHO should be the first thing anyone tries.

Comment: Yes, this works, but you have forgotten to mention, that you should open the cmd window as an administrator.  It is NOT the same as being a user with rights of administrator.

Comment: Opened CMD as administator, but still: *C:\ws>rmdir "C:\ws\preact-material-components" /s
C:\ws\preact-material-components, Are you sure (Y/N)? y
Toegang geweigerd.*  (**access denied**)

Comment: Still gives me "Access is denied"

Comment: Combining this with another answer's suggestion of `icacls foldername /reset /T` worked for me. (I'd earlier also taken ownership of the folder)

Comment: This really works for me. Thank you!

Comment: Remove-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '/s'.

Comment: `Rd /q /s` does not ask if it is OK to delete. It just removes the directory. I just stepped through a couple directories Opera Developer left.

Answer (score 9):

You can use Unlocker utility to delete such folders.

It is very simple to use and it is completely free.

Comment: To be specific the software is IOBit Unlocker - the above link is an affiliate link. This suggestion worked perfectly for me on Windows 10 to delete a domain user locked download.

Comment: @mogga: I'm pretty sure the link would have changed in the last 5 years now.

Comment: Every other solution didnt work. It was locked completely. IOBit savec my ass.

Comment: I tried most of solutions , like trying to use 'TAKEOWN' command , trying to change file permissions etc etc , however all I was getting was 'Access denied' error . Moreover when I tried listing group & owner of that folder (which was corrupted) through cygwin on windows , I was getting 'Unknown' user & group [drwxr-x--- 1 Unknown+User Unknown+Group 0 Sep 11 06:14 bin] . I tried using IOBit Unlocker & that worked like charm , it unlocked that folder & afterwards folder got deleted automatically .

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

download [SysInternals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062) and use the following utilities

use  Process Explorer and Process Monitor to find out whats happening with your file

or use the following stand alone utils

use AccessChk to get details not easily available via the GUI

use PSFILE to scan for any process that is holding the file open
then try the MoveFile utility to schedule a file delete in the next boot cycle.

The answer you're looking for will show up in the output of one of these utilities

Comment: Process Explorer has just helped me out with exactly this problem - great tool.

Answer (score 4):

When I run into a folder/file I can't delete and rebooting doesn't free the file.  I will add to the security setting of the file/folder the Everyone group and set the permissions to Deny Full Control.  Then when I reboot the machine, what ever was using the file/folder starts, it won't be able to read/write or lock the file/folder.  Finally with nothing being able to use the file/folder, you will be free to delete it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

No go with Windows 7 Ultimate x64.  Finally had to boot from a USB-based linux OS (which ignores file permissions in NTFS file systems) and delete the offending directory that way.

Comment: That's a bit much for a Windows user (even though I suggested the same thing before I read your answer ;)   ), but an rm -rf of the subdirectory tree is sure a lot faster than the other methods! The issue is that something could break when Windows starts up again and the offending process or whatever can't find the folder/files.

Answer (score 2):

I assume UAC is enabled and you are trying to delete the folder from Windows Explorer. You should run Windows Explorer as administrator (right click on the icon and select "Run as administrator") and then delete the folder.

The other alternative is to disable UAC, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: UAC is off and I am logged in as admin. I tried your method and still same problem. Plus UAC is just a warning and if you say Yes, it continues with its process.

Comment: @Tony UAC does actually do some other things.  I have some legacy applications that won't run under Windows 7 with UAC turned on even if you accept the prompts (in fact, even if you have the prompts turned so low you don't get any running these apps!)  I really wish I knew WHY this is, but it is.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this happens for files that were installed by some kind installer, like under the TrustedInstaller user.

You need to pwn the file first,

1. Right click the file, go to **Properties/Security/Advanced**.
2. Owner tab/Edit/Change the owner to you (Administrator), save.
3. Now you can go back to **Properties/Security/** and assume Full Control over the file

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the folder to your Desktop and deleting it there, odd, but has worked for me under similar circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (Windows required permission from user X, while being connected as user X…):

[image]

I fixed it using [unlocker](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=unlocker) (free, Microsoft Windows), then did:

[image]

[image]

After that, I could delete the directory without further issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a folder that was completely hosed on Windows Server 2019.  Couldn't take ownership, couldn't modify permissions, couldn't delete no matter what I tried.

Ended up being able to resolve it with the robocopy command using the /MIR switch with others.

```
robocopy \\source\data c:\data /R:10 /W:10 /MIR /SEC /EFSRAW /ZB /J /LOG:C:\LogFolder\logfile.log
```

I was syncing files and was able to clean up the same folder in the source location first, then /MIR deleted the folder in the source with the other switches above.

DISCLAIMER: /MIR will mirror source directory to destination, including deleting files in destination, so be sure you want destination to match source exactly before running it!

Answer (score 0):

For me, git's `bash.exe` was holding my folder open, so I had to manually stop the bash tasks.

### ***How to stop `bash.exe` tasks:***

1. Right-click the task bar
2. Task Manager
3. "Processes" tab
4. Look for `bash.exe`
5. For each `bash.exe`

   - Right-click > End Task