# Windows 7: Can't delete a folder when running as Administrator

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't delete folder and I am admin. “You need permission to perform this action. You require permission from…”](https://superuser.com/questions/204909/cant-delete-folder-and-i-am-admin-you-need-permission-to-perform-this-action)

I have a folder that has been created by an installer (iTunes) under:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

When I attempt to delete this folder it states:

> **You need permission to perform this action.**
>
> You require permission from the computer's administrator to make
>   changes to this folder.

However, my account is an Administrator account.

How can I remove this folder?

Comment: Have you tried restarting? The problem may be from Windows thinking that the folder is still being used - restarting fixes.

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on the folder -> Properties -> Seurity Tab -> Down to permissions

Set your permissions to allow.

Here's more info

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx

Or simply delete the folder after running Explorer as an administrator (via right-click).

Comment: The security tab is empty and there is no option for me to allow permissions. It simply states: "You do not have permission to view or edit this object's permission settings."

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to seize ownership of the folder. Under the security tab, click the Advanced button, then click the Owner tab.  You'll need to take ownership of the file and reset the permissions to allow you to delete it.

I'm curious which folder are you trying to delete.