# "You do not have permission to perform this action" when trying to delete a folder

Tags: hard-drive, windows-vista, file-permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't delete folder and I am admin. “You need permission to perform this action. You require permission from…”](https://superuser.com/questions/204909/cant-delete-folder-and-i-am-admin-you-need-permission-to-perform-this-action)

I'm logged in to my laptop on a Administrator account and I'm trying to delete a folder on my hard drive but i'm getting "You do not have permission to perform this action".

I've tried going into the the dos screen and deleting it that way but no luck.

Why won't it let me delete the folder even though i'm an Administrator?

Comment: You need to tell us what the folder is. There are some folders that are owned by System not by users (even admins) and so changes to them are rejected by Windows Explorer and the shell. Have you checked to see what are your "effective" permissions for that folder and who/what else has permissions and what they are? Maybe put up some screen shots.

Comment: It's just a folder that's been created by an application. It's definitely not a system file/folder. Under the "Security" tab its got listed "System" and my user profile and none of the boxes are checked. Also get access denied when attempting to give myself full permission. Its showing the user "SYSTEM" as owner too...??