# Can't delete folder as admin, asks for Admin User that doesn't exist - "You'll need to provide administrator permission to delete this folder"

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, file-permissions, administrator, acl

I am having a similar issue to the [user who posted here](https://superuser.com/questions/204909/cant-delete-folder-and-i-am-admin-you-need-permission-to-perform-this-action).

Basically, a folder in my Downloads (which shouldn't have any special permissions) won't allow me to delete it. When I try, I get a message stating

> "You'll need to provide Administrator permissions to delete this
>   folder"

I am logged in as an administrator (the only account on the PC besides "Guest"). When I click continue (with the admin icon on it), I get another message

> "You require permission from JOHND0447/johndoe to make changes to this
>   folder"

I'm not sure where the string with part of my username + 0447 is coming from. Anyone else ever encountered this?

Comment: Sounds like it was the owner of the file take ownership of the it did you try the solution in the other question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you should be able to do, if you are admin to the machine:

1. Right click the folder and choose properties.
2. Go to the security tab
3. Click 'Advanced'
4. Go to the Owner tab
5. Choose edit
   [image]
6. Select your correct user/ username and then check the box for "Replace own on subcontainers and objects"
7. Click OK

This should now allow you to delete the folder.