# .exe file need an administrator rights to delete

Tags: windows-10, administrator, unwanted-application

I have downloaded an .exe file called "nana_Windows_Media_Player_Firefox_and_Chrome_Plugin.exe" in order to copy this file to my computer.

I've copied it to my private folder on C:/. Once I copied it, my antivirus software (AVG) detected it as an unwanted file.

I have tried to remove it, but it requires administrator rights to delete it. Just to be clear - I'm the system administrator so I don't understand why it doesn't let me to delete it.

Nothing works. I tried to rename it, cut it and paste it in another folder, but nothing.

I've checked in the file properties at the security tab, and the file administrator is unknown and I can't change the administrator from over there.

When I'm trying to change it's folder name, it says that another program uses this folder and I should close it first.

What can I do to delete this file?

Comment: "AVG detected the copy as an unwanted file" - did AVG delete the copy? Are you trying to delete the original or the copy or both? Please [edit] your question to clarify. What is the full path where the original file is? And what is the full path where the copy is?

Comment: Use [Unlocker](http://www.askvg.com/download-unlocker-file-unlocking-utility-for-windows/) to delete the file.

Comment: @K.Rmth it's not working

Comment: Have you tried starting windows in safe mode and then delete the file?

Comment: Check if [this post](http://superuser.com/a/757751/183349) helps.

Comment: @Lucky it also doesn't help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force the deletion of a locked file that has no locking handle on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/1135565/how-to-force-the-deletion-of-a-locked-file-that-has-no-locking-handle-on-windows)

Answer (score -1):

I've experienced similar problems before like this. What worked for me was to enable the hidden 'Super Admin' user via the command prompt, sign out of the current account, sign in to the new 'Super Admin' account, and them delete the file. Otherwise, I've also found a free tool called "File assassin" to be really useful too if the first method doesn't work.

Comment: “Super Administrator” does not exist on Windows.  What account did you actually enable?

Comment: Are you talking about the built-in Administrator user?  I actually know how to enable the built-in Administrator.

Comment: If the author's Administrator user was unable to delete the file, it's very unlikely, the built-in Administrator would have been able to delete the file.  This could have been solved with their Administrator user, by simply taking ownership of the file, which would have been required for the built-in Administrator also.  To be clear the built-in Administrator does not have any additional permissions.  **There are a few differences with regards to the User Account Control (UAC) but that is about it.**