# How to force the deletion of a locked file that has no locking handle on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-permissions

When I try to delete the file, using the GUI it says

> The action cannot be completed because the file is open in another
>   program

And using the `del /f /q` command line it says

> Access is denied

I have tried unlocking the file with Unlocker, as well as trying to locate which process is using the file with the Resource Monitor or the Process Explorer, but no locking handle was found in either case.

I am able to rename or move the file, but not to delete it or change its content.

Comment: You can't edit/delete it even after copying/moving/renaming? If so, its either virus/antivirus or [NTFS file permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx).

Comment: I am the owner of the file and have the full read/write permissions of it. And disabling the anti virus doesn't doesn't unlock the file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We are always glad to help, but just to double-check (since you didn't elaborate), are you certain that this isn't a critical operating system file?

If you are confident that this isn't an essential OS or application file, you can always utilize a Linux Live CD of some type and navigate to the file accordingly.  Under those circumstances, it won't be constrained by the Windows operating system and can easily be deleted.

If you are trying to completely delete the `Windows.old` folder, that is understandably frustrating.  I have encountered similar problems following a Windows 10 upgrade, and was finally able to delete it by booting into a command prompt.  Try utilizing the following method:

1. While logged into Windows 10, open the **Run** window by holding <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
2. Type `shutdown /r /o /f /t 00` in the subsequent window, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. After the system reboots, click on **Troubleshoot**

   [image: Click on Troubleshoot]
4. Click on **Advanced Options**

   [image: Click on Advanced Options]
5. Click on **Command Prompt**

   [image: Click on Command Prompt]
6. The ensuing window will ask you to **Choose an account to continue**
7. Select a local administrator account, type in the appropriate password, and click on **Continue**
8. Within the command prompt, type `diskpart` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (as seen below)
9. In the command prompt, type `list volume` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
10. From the listed volumes, look for and verify the drive letter of your Windows 10 drive.
11. In the command prompt, type `exit` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

    [image: Command Prompt Window]
12. Ensure that you substitute "D" in the command below with the actual drive letter of your Windows drive as displayed from step 10 (above).
13. To delete the "Windows.old" folder, type `RD /S /Q "D:\Windows.old"` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
14. Close the command prompt window.
15. Back at the **Choose an option** window, click on **Continue** to restart the computer.

(Source:  [How to Delete Windows.old Folder in Windows 10](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2066-windows-old-folder-delete-windows-10-a.html))

Comment: It was a file from the Windows.old folder, I ran the Disk Clean-up, which deleted everything in this folder except this file

Comment: That definitely paints a different picture, and I have previously encountered the exact same scenario.  I updated my answer with what I did before to solve that problem.

Comment: Great that worked! And good job on adding the screenshots that helped

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Again, I encountered the exact same scenario after my first Windows 10 upgrade, and that tutorial worked for me, too.

Comment: In Windows.old folders this is usually (but possibly not always) due to a driver locking the file. In the Device Manager, find the device and disable it, then delete the file (or take ownership and delete), and then re-enable the device. Lots simpler than getting into the recovery console.

Comment: Thank you, I have an ACER laptop with precious little space and used your method to delete `C:\Recovery\Customizations\usmt.ppkg` which was 3.4G more than I could afford to spare.  I used `del` vs. `rd` since it is a file, not a folder.

Comment: Your answer contains image from another forum. It can be added from VirtualBox.

Comment: @Biswapriyo, yes it does... and that's why I specifically referenced the TenForums article at the end of my answer.  I appreciate your feedback, but I'm not too worried about having the TenForums watermark on the screenshots.  My top priority when I posted this answer was technical accuracy, not pristine screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MoveFile` from [Microsoft SysInternals utilities](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pendmoves.aspx).

It allows you to schedule a move or delete at next reboot. The operation will take place before the files are referenced.