# Have second drive from old laptop, cannot delete Program Files

Tags: windows, windows-10

I am on Windows 10 and have plugged in a second drive from my old laptop that is mostly full of files I need.  It works just fine, but I cannot delete D:\Program Files and a few other old Windows folders that I do not need and are taking up space.

I get a message 'You require permission from TrustedInstaller to make changes to this folder', but if I click the Try Again button I never get permission. I have given everyone permission on this folder and all subfolders, and made sure none of the files/folders are read only.  It still doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to delete these old unused Windows folders?

Comment: Why not just format the drive?

Comment: because it is over half full and I don't have anywhere to put the files right now.  Seems like a huge inconvenience to get an external drive, move off hundreds of gigs, format, then put hundreds of gigs back on just so I can wipe out some old MS folders

Comment: OK. It wasn't clear from your question that you wanted to save data from the drive. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I previously [posted an answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1135565/how-to-force-the-deletion-of-a-locked-file-that-has-no-locking-handle-on-windows/1135569#1135569) helping another user delete their lingering `Windows.old` folder following a Windows 10 upgrade.  You could potentially try a modified version of the same method, but the BitLocker on that drive may still be a deal-breaker.  You would also need to be *extremely* careful that you weren't accidentally targeting your current `Program Files` folder, instead!

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  If I can't figure out how to do it an easier way I may have to disable bitlocker and do this. This is very silly, though.  Win 10 must have some hardcoded logic in it - this isn't even from an upgrade.  It's just from an old laptop

Comment: But the critical piece of the puzzle is BitLocker.  It provides a very nice native capability for securing data on your hard drive, but it can also make the life of an IT professional rather difficult during scenarios like this one.

Comment: I had to do this, couldn't get anything else to work.  Yay for spending a couple days unencrypting/encrypting

Comment: That is a rather unfortunate scenario, but I am glad to hear that it ultimately worked out well for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try `TakeOwn /F "D:\Program Files"` first - this should switch the owner from Trusted Installer to Administrator.

Then run your normal Delete command.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried it from cmd run as Administrator and with the recursive switch: TakeOwn /R /F "D:\Program Files".  TakeOwn succeeded, but when trying to delete the UI looked different but still ended up failing with the following message: You require permission from MyDomain\MyUsername to make changes to this file.

Comment: How about `TakeOwn /F "D:\Program Files" /A /R` ?  That should force it to the local Administrators group - you need to be a member of local Administrators.  You might have to use `RD /S "D:\Program Files" ` rather than Explorer to delete the folder.

Comment: OK, tried the new command too but it didn't work.  I did just notice that all my files are read only, and now when I try to make all files/subfolders not read only I am getting an error.  The weird thing is I can move them into another folder on D like d:\piaFiles

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else works, you could boot with a Knoppix DVD (or other live Linux), and delete anything you want.  You can even delete the System Volume Information folder and the Recycle Bin.

Comment: sure, if I disabled bitlocker I could.  That's an all day thing, too, which I would rather avoid