# How can I delete these old system/driver files on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, drivers, filesystems, file-permissions, windows-10-upgrade

I've got a Windows 10 tablet that was upgraded from Windows 8. As a result of the upgrade, it kept some files in the C:\Windows.old folder. I ran the Disk Cleanup utility (diskmgr) to try and delete those, by checking the box to delete "Previous Windows Installation(s)." This did delete most of the contents of that folder; however, six system files were left in there, actually two copies of these three files:

- iaiogpioe.sys
- iaio2ce.sys
- iaiospi.sys

I tried to delete those and it said I couldn't because they were owned by TrustedInstaller. So, naturally, I changed ownership on those files to Administrators, and then gave Administrators full access. But then when I tried deleting them, it said they were in use by the system and so couldn't be deleted.

I was able to move them out of the C:\Windows.old folder, and into my Documents folder, thereby allowing me to delete the Windows.old folder. However, I still can't delete those six files which are now in my Documents folders. I am even able to rename them. I tried changing their file extension from "sys" to "pancakes." That works fine, but I am still unable to delete.

I even tried a third-party program called LockHunter, which indicated that the files weren't in use by any applications; however it was unable to delete them. It said I could attempt to delete the files upon reboot, but that, too, failed.

How do I delete these old system files?

Comment: Read through [my previous answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/1135565/how-to-force-the-deletion-of-a-locked-file-that-has-no-locking-handle-on-windows/1135569#1135569).  There are often some extra steps necessary to successfully delete the `Windows.old` folder following an upgrade.  Before you start the process, you should probably move those files back to where they were originally.

Comment: Thanks @Run5k. Booting into the recovery command prompt is what finally allowed me to delete those files.

Comment: It is good to hear that your system is back to normal, and I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft makes it sound like it is so easy. Run Disk Cleanup and select "Clean up system files", select everything and it is a done deal. It is another M$ "oops!".

The trick I have found is to take ownership as the user that is currently logged on the add the user that is currently logged on to the NTFS permissions as full. In both cases replace the changes throughout the entire folder structure. Then delete the folder. That should do the trick. If you have problems taking ownership or adding permission just say and I'll post the long version.