# How to get deletion rights for old Windows folder in cmd

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, file-permissions, icacls

I have an old Windows installation on a secondary HDD and I can't format it because there's data on it.

I therefore want to delete `E:\Windows` but haven't got sufficient rights.

So I first took ownership of everything:

```
takeown /R /D Y /F windows
```

Then I modified the ACLs to default:

```
icacls windows /reset /t /q /c
```

And then I deleted:

```
rmdir /s /q windows
```

But actually, icacls already failed on 6 folders.

```
windows\CSC\v2.0.6\namespace: Access denied
windows\CSC\v2.0.6\temp: Access denied
windows\CSC\v2.0.6\namespace\*: Access denied
windows\CSC\v2.0.6\temp\*: Access denied
windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Ngc\{DF2A28A6-5B19-4958-B762-2AB0124EA99D}: Access denied
windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Ngc\{DF2A28A6-5B19-4958-B762-2AB0124EA99D}\*: Access denied
```

(So now this is everything which remains in `E:\Windows`. Just to be sure, I also tried `icacls windows /grant Felix:F /t /q /c` which didn't help. But I checked and I am indeed the owner.)

So what are my options?

The answer doesn't have to involve the command-line. If there's a shell way to do it, that's just fine.

Comment: You should be able to utilize a modified version of the same method I posted in a previous question, regarding how to delete the `Windows.old` folder after a Windows 10 upgrade:  [How to force the deletion of a locked file that has no locking handle on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/1135565/how-to-force-the-deletion-of-a-locked-file-that-has-no-locking-handle-on-windows/1135569#1135569)

Comment: Why the downvote? @Run5k I'll try that now.

Comment: @Run5k It worked! As this question is different from the other, maybe make an answer here that links to the other?

Comment: That may be a bit of overkill, since it is close enough to possibly be considered the same type of problem.  If you simply want to up-vote the original answer, I will flag this one as a duplicate.  Ultimately, I am glad to have helped in some small way.

Comment: I had hoped this would get an answer without logging out of windows. But it seems there are ACLs which not even the admin can change.