# Remove the file c:\Recovery\Customizations\usmt.ppkg when it is locked by System?

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, process

How can I remove the file `c:\Recovery\Customizations\usmt.ppkg` when it is locked by System on Windows 10?

I cannot remove it because it seems to be used by another process.

I used process explorer to find out which process locks `usmt.ppkg`, it seems it is "System".

I am aware of the consequences of removing this file, but it should be possible to remove this file even if it is completely unsafe.

Safe mode doesn't seem to work either. And I can't kill the "System" process. I also can't use the "close handle" feature of process explorer because an error pops up saying "error opening process: the handle is invalid".

Can anybody offer a helping hand?

Comment: Needless to say, you should proceed with caution.  If you are really certain that you want to delete this file, you should be able to use a modified version of the instructions to delete the `Windows.old` folder after a Windows 10 upgrade:  [How to force the deletion of a locked file that has no locking handle on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/1135565/how-to-force-the-deletion-of-a-locked-file-that-has-no-locking-handle-on-windows/1135569#1135569).  Simply target your file with the `RD` command.

Comment: Cheers @Run5k ! I've followed the instructions in the link you gave and booted in command prompt. Next i simply move the usmt.ppkg file to another directory and rebooted the computer. Now i can move the usmt.ppkg to usb thumb drive (just in case) and my windows 10 is still working.

Comment: Glad to hear that it resolved the problem.

Comment: restart windows in recovery mode, open cmd and remove the file?