# 0 byte rar file can't be deleted

Tags: windows-10, command-line

A friend of mine tried to download a file, but it was cut off mid-download and she got stuck with a .rar file that has 0 bytes, but in the details it says 8MB. Pressing <kbd>Delete</kbd> doesn't do anything. `Cmd` can't find the file.

[image: 0 bytes]

[image: the cmd]

It says 8MB in the Details, but this won't let me post more than 2 images.

Comment: What happens if you restart the computer and try again?

Comment: Or press <f5> to refresh explorer

Comment: She tried restarting, nothing happened

Comment: `chkdsk /f e:` Help at all?

Comment: "attrib E:\CheatEngine66_NoSetup.rar" (see if it is "Hidden").  Can you do anything else with the file?  Rename it?  Move it?  Press Shift+Delete (not just Delete)?

Comment: NTFS ADS?  ([Streams](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/streams.aspx)) - this could explain the difference in file size and disk usage.

Comment: Hopefully someone else within the community can give you a reasonably simple suggestion that will work.  If not, this one is might be a bit more time consuming but it always seems to work:  [How to force the deletion of a locked file that has no locking handle on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/1135565/how-to-force-the-deletion-of-a-locked-file-that-has-no-locking-handle-on-windows/1135569#1135569)  Simply modify your potential target to be that specific file.

Answer (score 2):

You better boot the system in safe mode.

The problem might be that it might be open in some application. Sometimes the downloader itself which might be running in the background.

So, u better boot the pc in safe mode. Delete the file and restart the system.

That most probably fixes.

Or you can use some rescue disc like herons boot cd to open the mini xp by which you can delete modify or do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Use `dir /x` to find the short 8.3 name of the file.

Then use that name in the `del` command.

Comment: the file is not listed there

Comment: Not possible. If you can see it in Explorer then you can see it via `dir`. Perhaps the name is not what you think it is.