# $WINDOWS.~BT corrupted after failed W10 update, can't delete

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I have updated 7 machines to Build 15063 without a problem but number 8 is proving very difficult even though it is identical to others.

Twice now after a failure I get a "Setup cannot start... reboot" message but to no avail. I discovered that $WINDOWS.~BT was corrupted. Any attempt to delete it by changing permissions etc fails.

The content is a random file from WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64...\file.dll

The security tab gives "The requested security information is either unavailable or can't be displayed". The whole directory tree can be moved but not deleted even using Parted Magic. Changing ownership and permissions will permit moving of the file and its parent folder, then the rest of the tree can be deleted.

CHKDSK shows no errors.

After I move the file to \Temp I can restart setup.exe

Any ideas as to how to get rid of this pesky file apart from format and reinstalling from scratch

Comment: Is that folder in Windows 7 OS? Try with takeown, icacls, rd commands recursively.

Comment: Try utilizing a modified version of the following technique.  It should work:  [How to force the deletion of a locked file that has no locking handle on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/1135565/how-to-force-the-deletion-of-a-locked-file-that-has-no-locking-handle-on-windows/1135569#1135569).

Comment: run dis cleanup and delete here the old windows data

Comment: disk cleanup will also take out windows.old and I don't want to loose that yet. However as problem is the file at the end of the tree with non existant security settings I doubt it will work. I think I have 2 options, live with it or format the drive and reinstall. As this was the result of a failed upgrade and after 6 attempts by MS Answer Desk to get this machine updated I guess I'm going to have to reinstall anyway. Thanks for all the suggestions

Comment: Did you try the method described within the link to the previous answer that I posted?

Comment: Unfortunalely further attempts will not be possible. The mobo has died! That is possibly why the win 10 update failed and the files got corrupted. Until I get the mobo repaired I'll have to put this on the back burner. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

use `ICALCS` to reset files permissions: :

1. Press windows key + X and choose (Command Prompt Admin) or Run `cmd` as Administrator
2. Select target folder
3. To reset all the files permissions, type:

   `icacls * /T /Q /C /RESET`

After that, the files permissions will be reset and you can delete the folder

Comment: Didn't work - "Access Denied"

Comment: @Sabreur Try `icacls "c:\$WINDOWS.~BT" /grant:r UserName:(OI)(CI)F /T` where UserName is the name of an Adminstrator.