# How to delete files used by Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I installed a program named "fences". Than I just deleted the main file from the PC, and now the folder is left with only two `.dll` files. When I try to remove them it says the file is being used by some other program. Then I did some research how to remove those files. I found Unlocker. It failed to remove the files, but at least it told me which other program is using those files; that was Windows Explorer –
but when I try to hit the "Unlock" button, Windows Explorer just closes. 
Below is the screenshot:
[image]
Because of this my desktop icon is not displaying; I can't even add any more icons to the desktop. 
How can I recover from this: delete the files and use my PC normally?

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Are the files still open after a reboot? If so, you could boot into Safe Mode Command Line and delete from there.

Comment: You should be able to utilize [this method](https://superuser.com/questions/1135565/how-to-force-the-deletion-of-a-locked-file-that-has-no-locking-handle-on-windows/1135569#1135569) and simply modify the target to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

Put the file you deleted back in place, and then uninstall Fences properly.

Note: you may be able to "repair" it via Add/Remove programs instead of finding a copy of the file.

Option 2:

Close Explorer, use Task Manager to start a command prompt, delete files via command prompt, restart Explorer.  Then dig through your registry and remove references to Fences.