# When can a file be in use by a process when it is not in use by a process?

Tags: windows, windows-10, process-explorer

Forgive the riddle-like question, but that's what I'm experiencing (I think). What I'm trying to do is delete a specific file. When I originally tried to delete it, Explorer tells me it's in use by System. What I did was to deny Full Control to NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM (the "user" under which the process "System" was running, as told by [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)) on the file, and restart the machine.

After restarting, I go to delete the file and get a File In Use dialogue saying "The action can't be completed because the file is open in another program". I return to the ever useful Process Explorer to search for that file name (my default method for finding what process has locked a file) but when searching for Handle or DLL substring, Process Explorer returns 0 results, as if the file is not in use by any process at all. I'm running Process Explorer as Administrator by the way. I was even able to rename the file and restart again, but still cannot delete it.

Can anyone elighten me as to how this happens? How can I find out what process is holding on to that file, so I can kill it and delete the damned thing?

Edit: [Run5k](https://superuser.com/users/650163/run5k) suggested this a duplicate of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1135565/how-to-force-the-deletion-of-a-locked-file-that-has-no-locking-handle-on-windows), and although it provides a solution to my specific problem, I would like an answer explaining *why* I can't find out what process is using the file I wish to delete.

Comment: Note, it really is an exercise in futility trying to lock the system account out of anything.

Comment: @FrankThomas What makes you say that? Does the system account somehow circumvent traditional NTFS permissions? thanks for the link Run5k, that does seem to be a method to do what I need to do (and is my exact situation as well) but I would still like a good answer to the theoretical part of my question

Comment: Hi @OilyBusiness, Welcome to SuperUser. We're here to provide answers to questions, not speculate why something is not working. This question will therefor be closed as being a duplicate at some point, because otherwise this question is simply speculating which is considered Off-Topic. See the helpcenter for more information

Comment: I'd argue that this is not asking for speculation, because I've experienced this many times, under different Windows builds, on different machines. I believe this is intended behavior for Windows in certain situations. I think this has something to do with the way Windows works and that the information is likely available somewhere, and I hope that someone with that knowledge could answer this question.

Comment: I would also like to note that I've searched for duplicates and have not found anything that answers my question.

Comment: @OilyBusiness, there are too many possible reasons why you can't find something.  One reason could be that you suck at finding stuff.  :-)  Only kidding.  But people need to be able to replicate your particular situation and we can't do that from the information in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I do understand your point of replicating the problem. Next time I will be more direct with my question rather than including my entire scenario, because this simply is not a duplicate but I understand that by including my scenario, it seems that way. The other question is asking how to delete locked files and I'm really asking a question about the nature of locked files in Windows, sometimes locked files _just do not show as locked_ and there must be something I'm missing there. No matter, off to another forum! Thank you all for your input.