# How do I delete a file without 'modify' permissions in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Only the "TrustedInstaller" has full control, it's a System32 file, and I can't even modify the permissions. I did a search but found nothing. I'll add more information to the question as needed, I'm not sure what else there is.

I'm trying to replace a keyboard.dll with my modded file. The installation as a separate keyboard option in the language list isn't working.

Comment: What file are you trying to delete and why? How was it installed?

Comment: Updated with info.

Comment: If you are **certain** that you want to delete this particular file, you can utilize [this method](https://superuser.com/questions/1135565/how-to-force-the-deletion-of-a-locked-file-that-has-no-locking-handle-on-windows/1135569#1135569) and modify the proposed target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason *TrustedInstaller* was added in Vista was to prevent people from replacing system files, as that's generally a very, very bad idea.

If you must do this, you will have to [take ownership](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753659%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) of the file and add a permission to allow you to modify the file.

Answer (score 0):

You ***might*** be able to accomplish this if you boot into safe mode with command prompt and delete/replace from there.  If you're not sure how to boot into Win 10 safe mode with command prompt, just Google it.  I have read a few different ways of achieving this so choose the method that's works for you.