# I Require Permission From Myself to Delete a Folder

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions

The folder I want to delete isn't a system file (it's in my WAMP document folder). When I try to delete it I get this message:
[image]
After providing admin permissions I get the below message:
[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If you are certain that you want to delete that folder, you can utilize [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1135565/how-to-force-the-deletion-of-a-locked-file-that-has-no-locking-handle-on-windows/1135569#1135569) and modify the target accordingly.

Comment: Make sure the files in the folder you also have the permission, check the permissions or the owner of the folder. Make sure the files in the folder are not is use.