# Deleting Corrupted Files on Windows

Tags: windows, file-corruption

Deleting corrupted files seems to be a real pain. All the suggestions out there recommend either formatting the drive or using Linux. What to do when both of these are not an option?

Note, that using `robocopy`, `remdir`, and `del` in the terminal, or `remove-item` in powershell are all returning the same error - `"the file is corrupted or unreadable"`. Even `echo 'hello' > <filename>` is giving the same error.

Has anyone come across a simple and quick - windows only - working solution, that does not require third party tools?

**EDIT:** My question specifically asks for a simple - no linux - and, quick - no full disk scans - solution. My question does not relate to locked files, rather corrupted ones, and therefore, I do not see it as a duplicate to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1135565/how-to-force-the-deletion-of-a-locked-file-that-has-no-locking-handle-on-windows) post.

Comment: Maybe you need to use the native Windows error correction tool first.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia - If your refering to `chkdisk`, I've seen it suggested. But I'm specifically looking for a "simple" answer. I should've been more clear. "Simple" here, means "Quick". Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Yes, that one in CLI or what is basically the same tool in a graphical interface. Right-click the drive, properties and you'll find the tools tab. It can't be easier than that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force the deletion of a locked file that has no locking handle on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/1135565/how-to-force-the-deletion-of-a-locked-file-that-has-no-locking-handle-on-windows)

Comment: @Run5k That post is about locked files, not corrupted ones.

Comment: @sh7411usa Yes, it is... but the underlying goal is essentially the same, and it should still work.

Comment: running `chkdsk` is the quickest way to fix. If disk metadata has been corrupted, obviously nothing can't be read or written without fixing the metadata. By the time you finish typing this answer, `chkdsk` may have already finished its job

Comment: it seems that `chkdsk` is the way to go then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your filesystem is inconsistent, deleting corrupted files probably won't fix it. File corruption is a symptom, not the core issue. The correct next step is to run `chkdsk /f`. Easier solutions are insufficient solutions.