# Deleting 'read only file'

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions, read-only

I've modified a file in AppData/LocalLow to be 'read only'. Then I'm trying to undo the 'read-only' and I'm getting that I need the permissions of myself - meaning the permission of my user that now I am being logged in with this user.
Also I can't delete the file. Any help?

Comment: Do you have the necessary permissions for the Appdata folder itself?

Comment: @Leathe I asks for the permission of the user that is now being logged in.

Comment: Can you uncheck `Read-only` on the LocalLow folder itself and then try to delete the file?

Comment: Also see [Can't delete folder and I am admin. “You need permission to perform this action. You require permission from…"](http://superuser.com/questions/204909/cant-delete-folder-and-i-am-admin-you-need-permission-to-perform-this-action)