# win10x64 - access denied removing file? unable to resolve

Tags: windows-10, permissions, file-permissions

I looked through - [Can't delete folder and I am admin. "You need permission to perform this action. You require permission from..."](https://superuser.com/questions/204909/cant-delete-folder-and-i-am-admin-you-need-permission-to-perform-this-action/790157#790157)

but can't update that as i'm a newbie here.  tried a "take ownership" script i've added to the context menu which has worked in the past, no change.

tried unlocker and normally when that fails, 10Bit unlocker with forced mode delete works.  not this time though.

process explorer says the thumbs.db file (only file in this folder tree) is in use by system.  i've been able to take ownership via security tab in the past but this time around it's really weird.

under security on file properties it just says "you must have read permissions etc". had it before and no worries. go into advanced and on the permissions, auditing and effective access tabs i have the "continue" option but on clicking i just straight to the "permissions/effective access" tabs and both just say:

you do not have permission to view or edit ........

under owner i just see "unable to display current owner", click change and get the above message again.

at 1 point it did say i needed permission from, well me.  my username which i am signed in as.

normally i'd get the delete prompt on screen, force a chkdsk to kill off handles and hit delete as soon as it's done but i'm 3 days in to a 7 day video encode and don't want to waste that time.

i hate windows sometimes.  help?

--EDIT

thanks but the fix i saw on the other thread was to  disable "display file icons on thumbnails" in folder's view.  i never had this enabled though.  choosing to always show icons instead of thumbs worked but i then had to disable this as i want thumbnails, just no thumbs.db created.

Comment: thanks but the fix i saw on the other thread was to disable "display file icons on thumbnails" in folder's view. i never had this enabled though. choosing to always show icons instead of thumbs worked but i then had to disable this as i want thumbnails, just no thumbs.db created.